# Stumped on how to make something default on selection

Tags: html

I would like the "" option to be the default option in the following select statement but it will not default to that option.  I have tried     `<OPTION  value="" selected="selected"></OPTION>` and it doesnt work.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<td class="lblhd">
                    <SELECT  tabindex="71" ID="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/Last_Sale_Price_text" NAME="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/Last_Sale_Price_text" onchange="last_sale_price_dropdown();">
                        <OPTION  value="" ></OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="Subject prior sale price/date was not available in public records">
                            <xsl:if test="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/Last_Sale_Price_text = 'Subject prior sale price/date was not available in public records'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="selected">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="true" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    Subject prior sale price/date was not available in public records.
                                </OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="Subject prior sale price/date was not available in MLS">
                                    <xsl:if test="PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/Last_Sale_Price_text = 'Subject prior sale price/date was not available in MLS'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="selected">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="true" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    Subject prior sale price/date was not available in MLS.
                                </OPTION>

                    </SELECT>
                </td>
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect `last_sale_price_dropdown()` is where your problem is. You might want to look at that

Comment: `all that function does is check 2 fields and forces someone to pick an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selected attribute to that field to make it the default:

```
<OPTION  value="" selected="selected" ></OPTION>
```

Answer (score 0):

what i understood is, Actually it selecting the option as expected. but it is not being shown. Just try giving a value to it

change

```
<OPTION  value=""></OPTION>
```

to

```
<OPTION  value="" selected="selected">select a option</OPTION>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TZMT5/

Comment: this does not work as i stated above---gives and xml parse error

Comment: i have updated the answer.. please check if it solve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:element name="option">
    <xsl:attribute name="selected">
        <xsl:text>selected</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

or

```
<option selected="selected"></option>
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="true" />
```

is saying take the value of the xml node named true and display it's value!

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_value_of.asp

http://jsfiddle.net/Q55V3/2/

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<true>
    Hello, world!
</true>
```

test.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Option Select With XSL</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <select>
                <option>Hello</option>
                <option>World</option>                  
                <xsl:element name="option">
                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">
                        <xsl:text>selected</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </select>
            <span><xsl:value-of select="true"/></span>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on in your script like mixed up styles in capitalizing. To avoid confusion you could change everything into lowercase for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Does your html validate? When pages do not validate, browser behaviour becomes undefined. Also, even if the page validates, if the xsl bits are not recognized by your browser (I do not know if they are or are not), I think that could possibly cause this issue.

Try removing all of the extra text from inside each of the  tags, set one of the option tags to be selected by default, and see if the select works as expected.